# Plotting the overall trend using ggplot for longitudinal data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to plot the overall trend for longitudinal data. I am using the `sleepstudy` data in `lme4` package to demonstrate my problem.

```
 library("lme4")
 library("ggplot2")
    p1 <- ggplot(data = sleepstudy, aes(x = Days, y = Reaction, group = Subject))
    p1 + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(col = Subject) ,size=2)
```

When i plot the longitudinal trajectories for each individual, I got this plot
[image]

Here I am interested in finding the overall trend based on all subjects. For an example based on the above plot we can see an upward trend in general.  In general this trend can be anything like linear, quadratic etc. Is this any way to plot this overall trend ?

I tried this . But i got smoothed curves for each subject instead of getting the overall trend

```
p1  + geom_point() +  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Can anyone help me figure this out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I understand correctly:

```
library("lme4")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = sleepstudy, aes(x = Days, y = Reaction))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = Subject), alpha = .3)+
  geom_smooth()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

As you can see you'll have `loess` function:

```
> geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

---

If you need `lm` just specify the argument `method` into `geom_smooth`.

```
library("lme4")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = sleepstudy, aes(x = Days, y = Reaction))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = Subject), alpha = .3)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  labs(title = "Linear Model (LM)")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. Although the data has a linear trend in this situation, sometimes it can be quadratic. In that case what type of smoothing method can we use ?

Comment: It depends on what you would like to show. However, if you need quadratic take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42764028/3519756)

Comment: Thank you . One more thing i have in mind. In the plot that i showed you , there are smoothed curves for each individual.  So is there any way to get the average of those smoothed curves and plot that as the overall trend ? I may want to try this because these are longitudinal data

Comment: Probably what you need is a regression model. Look at `glm` or `gam`